# How to hide nvd3 tooltip on scroll

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm trying to hide the toolip of a line chart when user scrolls the page.

```
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .interpolate("cardinal")        
        .margin({left: 50})
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .duration(500)
        .showLegend(true)
        .showYAxis(true)
        .showXAxis(true);

    //... get data and plot it.

    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.hidden(true);
        chart.tooltip.hidden(true);
    });
```

None of the above worked. Am i missing something?

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry, no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

I could handle this using angular 12 and https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3. In my case on the touchscreen devices when scrolling and touching over the chart, the tooltip got fixed on the top left of the screen.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
...
export class NameComponent {
    constructor() {}

    @HostListener('touchmove') touchmove(): void {
    d3.select(window).on('scroll', () => {
      d3.selectAll('.nvtooltip').style('opacity', '0');
    });
  }
}
```

https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/427#issuecomment-382711323